# Using Google Adwords Conversion Tracking pixel without the script

Tags: google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I am trying to implement Google Adwords conversion tracking within the confines of a very restrictive process management tool, which strips out any `<script>` content I use.

As the tracking code consists of the script and an image tag, and both include ID and conversion label, I wondered if I can use the image without the script.

i.e not this:

```
<!-- Google Code for CONVERSION NAME -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = XXXXXXX;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "YYYYYYY";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
```

but only this image tag:

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/XXXXXXX/?label=YYYYYYY&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
```

And this again not:

```
</div>
</noscript>
```

Will this work? I am posting this as a question here as our system leaves few options for testing (process needs to go offline in order to implement changes).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. You can use just the image tag, in fact, when you use the script part, in the end, that code appends one image to your html.